# How to use "where" through cmd shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, path

On Windows 10, I lost all my path variables and now I want to recover every shortcut (code, notepad, npm, java, etc).

`'where' is not recognized ...`  ,
`'code' is not recognized ...`

I don't want to look for each file individually through the explorer. Now I wanted to use "where" to gather paths quickly, but it turns out that it does not work because I've deleted its own path.

I noticed that I have this file `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe` installed, but changing `PATH` from System (or User ??) variable won't work. How to fix it in order to run it any`where`?

Comment: check variable **`%pathext%`** **`PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`** order and check if you have some other file named **`where`** with different .eXtension using: **`dir /b /a:a /s \where.exe`**

Comment: Check: `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\where.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-where_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_13c446a37d881982\where.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-where_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_1e18f0f5b1e8db7d\where.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed that I have this file `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe` installed, but changing PATH from System (or User ??) variable won't work. How to fix it in order to run it anywhere?

The "basic" (default) `Path` (`System`) variable under Windows 10 for `Windows\System32` is `%SystemRoot%\system32`. Adding this path to your `Path` (`System`) variables *should* enable `where` from the command line, I believe.

Note that this doesn't include any other standard `Path` (`System`) variables, including:

```
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

and likely `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared`. This also doesn't include standard `PATH` (`User`) variables such as `C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`.

> I don't want to look for each file individually through the explorer. Now I wanted to use "where" to gather paths quickly, but it turns out that it does not work because I've deleted its own path.

As already indicated in [harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1640078/302907), `where` cannot do what you wish. It doesn't "discover" executable files or "remember" `Path`\`PATH` variables. If the relevant paths do not exist in your environment variables, `where` cannot "find" those paths. You are going to have to go through Explorer\executables manually unless you use a system restore, as already detailed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was using the wrong path `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe` instead of simply `C:\Windows\System32`. However it didn't find a thing. I ended up using the explorer anyways

Answer (score 1):

`Where` works by searching the PATH. If the path is incorrect,
it will not find anything.

The easiest way to recover your PATH is, if you have System Restore enabled,
to rollback Windows to a time before this change was done.

For more details see the tutorial
[How to Do a System Restore of Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html).